# How can I consolidate the views that are auto generated by nodequeue

Tags: views, nodes

I'm using the nodequeue module to potentially create a large number of queues. With each new queue I create, a view is auto generated for that queue. Ultimately, I want to be able to access each queue as a view, but I'm wondering two things.

1. Are there performance implications to have in potentially hundreds of views created?
2. Isn't there a better way to display nodequeues in a view? why does there have to be a different view for each nodequeue ? isn't there a way to pass the relationship in through a contextual filter?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there performance implications to have in potentially hundreds of views created?

Views are just queries. If you're concerned about performance use `caching` in Views under the `advanced settings` for each view. There are contrib modules that enable caching for all views.

> Isn't there a better way to display nodequeues in a view? why does there have to be a different view for each nodequeue ? isn't there a way to pass the relationship in through a contextual filter?

Possibly, but then your view(s) would only be accessible from say 1 url via the contextual filter ... a freedom of the Page view provided by the nodequeue is that as a site builder you can define unique url routes per view.